# No C++ Templates in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have downloaded and installed the RC version of the VS2012 [VS2012_RC_ULT_ENU.iso](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/7/697096F6-4EEA-4704-AF2D-F3BAF57C7634/VS2012_RC_ULT_ENU.iso). Now, when I start Visual Studio, there's no project templates for C++ programs.

Here's this problem reported from someone else:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745797/no-c-projects-in-vs2012-rc-premium

Is this problem only for me or do I have to do something special?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745402/error-message-cant-find-localized-resources

It looks like your installation or machine somehow got in a bad state.

I would try in this order:

1. Repairing VS installation
2. Reinstalling VS
3. Reinstalling Windows and then VS

You may also want to try with a different installation media.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed my OS but I'd guess that re-installing it would fix it, since it's working fine now.